# Sorting Lookup Values

Tags: lookup-column, sorting

I have a list that breaks down periods within our accounting calendar. P1, P2, P3,...P12. The problem I am having is when I perform a lookup on this column it's sorting by alphabetical order and it puts it in this order: P1, P10, P11, P12, P2, P3, etc. This column is a string column type so i can't sort numerically. I'm not a developer so coding would be lost on me.

Any ideas on how to fix without programming so it doesn't sort that way? Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While not exactly like your accounting structure, you could name them P01, P02, etc and it will sort as you'd expect.

Comment: Thanks PirateEric!!! That works for what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [sp2013filteredlookup.codeplex.com](https://sp2013filteredlookup.codeplex.com/). It can uses views, so you can manage the custom order of the lookup in the view.